# Regular expression matching with several conditions

Tags: c#, regex

I have a textual input that says:

The printer goes from ready state to working state when the following conditions are met:
1. paper is present
2. connection is proper
3. power connection

How do I parse this text as three sub divisions (1. source state, 2. destination state,  3. condition)?

Is it possible to do this using reqular expression matching in C#?

Comment: You could spot "number then dot" with a regex, sure, but what if one of the points is "there power is more than 3.5 V" etc? I suspect this may be more subtle than is obvious

Comment: Do you need these matchings: text between "from" and "to", then from "to" and "when" and then the text after "are met:"?

Comment: @MarcGravell [0-9]|[a-z][.] would be sufficient to get the conditions right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below

```
fromstate = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "from (.*?) state(.*?) to (.*?) state(.*?)are met:(.*)").Groups[0].Value; //from state

tostate = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "from (.*?) state(.*?) to (.*?) state(.*?)are met:(.*)").Groups[2].Value; //to state

conditions = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "from (.*?) state(.*?) to (.*?) state(.*?)are met:(.*)").Groups[4].Value; //conditions
```

Comment: this will not work when there are more words inbetween from and state eg. "from the current working state", Is there any better way to match.

Comment: @user1237256  You didn't provide that information when you asked the question.  Modify the regular expression to support it.

Comment: yeah i completely agree with that. is there any regular expression which supports "from [anything in between] state" ?

Comment: The above one will work with that. Else can you post your complete statement?